# Problema com comparação de String no AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Boa noite,
Pessoal to com um problema aqui, to usando um código ajax pra fazer verificação se um cpf já tá cadastrado sem da refresh na página pra não perder os dados, e retornando uma string com um valor criptografado em sha1 pra comparação e saber se já existe cadastro com o cpf no banco, mas o ajax não consegue comparar a string, e se eu do alert no resultado ele printa certinho a variável de resultado vinda do php certinho, já procurei e em fóruns americanos disseram que era só colocar $.trim() mas isso não ajudou também, se alguém puder me ajudar ou sugerir algo agradeço.Os códigos:

Ajax:

```
function VerificaCPF(strCPF)
    {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'daoAssociado.php',
        data: {action: 'VerificaCPF', cpf: strCPF},
        success: function(resultado)
        {
          if(resultado == '88e9d785061a31f8bae950b8e231f40426b5496c')
          {
            return false;
          }
          else if (resultado == '4b2c518cb740685b1b29f477283165b732651f05')
          {
            return true;
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

php:

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty(($_POST['action'])))
  {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    switch($action)
    {
      case 'VerificaCPF':
        consultarCPF($conectar);
      break;

      case 'VerificaUsuario':
        consultarUsuario($conectar);
      break;
    }
  }

function consultarCPF($conectar)
  {
    $cpf                    = sha1($_POST['cpf']);
    $queryVerificarCpf      = "exec usp_verificarExistenciaCpf @cpf = ?";
    $parameterVerificarCpf  = array($cpf);
    $query_Resultado        = sqlsrv_query($conectar, $queryVerificarCpf,      $parameterVerificarCpf) or die(header("Location:erronobanco.php"));
    $array_Resultado        = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query_Resultado);
    $totalDeCpf             = $array_Resultado['total'];

    if($totalDeCpf != 0)
    {
      echo '88e9d785061a31f8bae950b8e231f40426b5496c';
    }
    else
    {
      echo '4b2c518cb740685b1b29f477283165b732651f05';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não está tendo problema com comparação, mas sim com retorno. Atualmente sua requisição é assíncrona, daí não faz sentido você retornar dados sobre ela diretamente no código. Outro problema é que você não retorna nada no escopo de `VerificaCPF`.

Se sua requisição fosse síncrona, você poderia obter suas informações diretamente. Infelizmente ou felizmente, requisições síncronas serão removidas no futuro, pois estragam a interação do usuário com a página.

Requisições síncronas param a execução do código, afetando a página em torno até que se terminem. Uma requisição dessas "pausa" tudo enquanto a mesma não se termina. `for (; xhr.readyState !== 4 ;);`, é como um loop infinito que quebra até a requisição ser feita, só que isso é algo nativo.

O que eu recomendaria você fazer é usar funções como callbacks, passando argumentos extras para elas. Eu atualmente faço assim: retorno um objeto instanciado de uma interface, onde eu espero serem definidos eventos como `done` por chamadas. Mas, para deixar o código mais básico vou deixar um callback especificado em um parâmetro da sua função (agora falta o callback de erro de requisição).

```
function VerificaCPF(strCPF, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'daoAssociado.php',
        data: {
            "action": 'VerificaCPF',
            "cpf": strCPF
        }
    }).done(function(resultado) {
        var valid = '4b2c518cb740685b1b29f477283165b732651f05'
        callback(resultado === valid)
    })
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, eu percebi ontem também que o problema estava no retorno ela não tava retornando então eu mudei a sequencia de verificação e parei de retorna true or false pra um else if e coloquei ela la dentro direto

Answer (score 1):

Tem várias maneiras que você resolver isso, porém o problema que você está enfrentando é de escopo de execução.

Veja, como sua requisição é assíncrona os returns dentro da sua ajax call on success não fazem sentido, pelos seguintes motivos:

1. Princípio de closure (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp) o seu return está em outro escopo e não no escopo da function `VerificaCPF`
2. Chamada assíncrona. Quando sua chamada ajax receber a resposta o escopo de execução do javascript já passou pela chamada da function `VerificaCPF`. por isso um `var result = VerificaCPF()` não funciona.

Uma solução possível é usar uma callback function.

Por exemplo:

```
function funcaoDeCallback(resultado) {
      if(resultado == '88e9d785061a31f8bae950b8e231f40426b5496c')
      {
        return false;
      }
      else if (resultado == '4b2c518cb740685b1b29f477283165b732651f05')
      {
        return true;
      }
}

function VerificaCPF(strCPF, callBack)
{
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'daoAssociado.php',
    data: {action: 'VerificaCPF', cpf: strCPF},
    success: function(resultado)
    {
      callBack(resultado);
    }
  });
}

VerificaCPF('12345678912', funcaoDeCallback);
```

Assim você pode usar a function `funcaoDeCallback` no seu HTML para fazer o feedback adequado para o usuário.